Gas burner "kick off" trips off my fuse box
This phenomenon occurs infrequently: when multiple electrical devices are on, the RCD trips.
I think I managed to isolate the issue:

there is one specific fuse that leads to "tripping";

the most likely device to cause it my gas burner - but only when it starts (i.e. if it's already on, it's a non-issue);

on its own, the burner does not cause any problem, but only in conjunction with multiple other devices on the same fuse (e.g. kettle, extractor, microwave, all on at once).


The burner in question is Logic System s18IE.
I've found a similar post but I am not sure I fully understand the lingo there... Also, I have no idea how to go about fixing it?
If the bottom line is "get a professional electrician", it's fine - although so far, all those I spoke with said that if I cannot replicate the problem 100% of the time, they are reluctant to even examine the problem.

It sounds like everything is working as expected.  It is you causing the problem, too much on at the same time.  A RCD/circuit breaker is rated for so much power in amps.  Once you try to pull more than the rated amps, they trip.  A kettle and microwave are both near the top end, add the fan and burner, you go over.

What ignition system does your gas burner/hob use? A spark ignition? A hot surface? A pilot flame?

I don't know how to find the type of ignition - where do I find this information? Also, re: working as intended, in the past it didn't use to happen... So I am a bit concerned.

In the past it didn't happen. - Did you have a different microwave or kettle back then? Microwaves especially have been getting more and more powerful. Perhaps where you used to have a 900W device you now have 1200W or 1500W or more? In the US they need a circuit all to themself because of the high power consumption. Sounds like you're maybe in the UK, so you might be able to have a couple more things on the same circuit, but not that much more.

Nope no change whatsoever... Although kettle is getting old. Microwave is 900w only. I have a PC, television and A/V receiver on that circuit too
